# Scrapy pipeline mysql error

Tags: scrapy, pipeline, importerror

When I wrote the Scrapy\pipeline and then I tried to use scrapy crawl dmoz,
an error occured:

```
File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 42, in load_object 
raise ImportError("Error loading object '%s': %s" % (path, e)) 
ImportError: Error loading object 'tutorial.pipelines.Tutorialpipeline': DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

### UPDATE

the problem is fixed. when I used the pip install mysql-python, it installed a 32bits version of mysql-python, I uninstalled it and download a 64bits version.

however, I met another problem, when I run the spider, it shows that:

```
 _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064,"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc,pic)values ('xe4\xbe\x9b\xe5\xba.......' at line 1")
```

I am not sure what happened,could anybody help me figure it out?

here is how I write the mysql insert function in pipeline

```
  def _conditional_insert(self,tx,item):
        tx.execute('insert into raw(title,area,date,sclass,link,desc,pic) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s) '
               (item['title'],item['area'],item['date'],item['sclass'],item['link'],item['desc'],item['pic']))
```

Comment: Are you sure this code is where your error occurs ?

Comment: @dvhh I figured it out. that beause the version of mysql-python.

Comment: post an answer for your question for future reference

Comment: @dvhh I already update my question

Comment: updating the question is probably not enough, plus you are free to select your answer as THE answer for your question

Comment: as for your sql question you should try to check the query in an sql client first

Answer (score 1):

the problem is fixed. when I used the pip install mysql-python, it installed a 32bits version of mysql-python, I uninstalled it and download a 64bits version.